# How to get Install OCI8 Extension in Cpanel/WHM to connect with Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, installation, cpanel, whm, oci8

I am looking to get install OCI8 Extension over Cpanel/WHM. I am using VPS Hostgator. The Problem is that I can't able to get install OCI8 Extension. I am looking to get connect Oracle Database through PHP using oci_connect() function.

While getting using the oci_connect function it gives an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /home/advanced/public_html/test/test.php on line 6

So Wanted to know How Should I able to get install OCI8 Extension over Cpanel/WHM ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy,

You can install the OCI8 Extension through WHM -> Software -> Module Installers.  On this screen you will want to click "PHP Pecl".  When a search bot appears, you will want to search for OCI8.

In the results there will be a module named "oci8" with the description "Extension for Oracle Database".  You can click the install button to install this module.

The install will fail if you do not also have the "Oracle Instant Client" installed before hand as OCI8 depends on the Oracle Instant Client.  You will want to install the following beforehand:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html

Cheears!

Answer (score 0):

visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html it shows complete guide.  (for windows ans linux)

you can download the RPM and with Root access to your vps you can install the RPM as guided. then you may install oci8 from shell or from WHM PHP libraries/extensions installation page.